# What's a girl's name meaning mixed emotions?

Tags: names

Does anyone know a girl's name meaning mixed emotions? I want to use it for a character I'm writing about.
I also want it to sound cutesy and wholesome (something that rolls off the tongue easily). Here are some names I like (connotation wise):
Helen,
(Mayybe?) Mei,
Eden,
Natsuki,
Fiona,
Lylian

Comment: You could call her Janice or maybe Jane from  the Rinman god Janus.

Comment: Hello, Mei, welcome to EL&U!  Perhaps [Daimantina](https://www.momjunction.com/baby-names/diamantina/) would work? But this question is too [subjective](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), so is likely to be closed soon. Please give some time to taking the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for more guidelines for asking questions. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If the mixed emotions are of the bitter-sweet variety, *Mara* may work.

As [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mara_(name)#:%7E:text=It%20is%20of%20Hebrew%20origin,of%20her%20husband%20and%20sons.&text=Mara%20means%20joy%20in%20Arabic%20and%20can%20be%20a%20unisex%20name.) explains:

> It is of Hebrew origin, and the meaning of Mara is "bitter", which carries the implication "strength". Biblical: Naomi, mother-in-law of Ruth, claimed the name Mara as an expression of grief after the deaths of her husband and sons.